# Laravel routing (?) problems

Tags: php, laravel

So I just uploaded my site from my local dev environment to my server.
But there's a problem. Only the index page loads. I've mapped some
controllers to different routes like this:

```
//controller detection
Route::controller(Controller::detect());

//site routes
Route::get('/','site@index');
Route::get('about','site@about');
Route::get('blog','site@blog');
Route::get('downloads','site@downloads');
Route::get('products','site@products');
Route::get('shop','site@shop');

//admin routes
Route::get('login','admin@login');

//ajax functions
Route::get('loadnews/(:num)','ajax@loadnews');
Route::post('sendmessage','ajax@sendmessage');
Route::post('loadblog','ajax@loadblog');
Route::post('loadblogdetails','ajax@loadblogdetails');

Event::listen('404', function()
{
    return Response::error('404');
});

Event::listen('500', function()
{
    return Response::error('500');
});

Route::filter('before', function()
{
    // Do stuff before every request to your application...
});

Route::filter('after', function($response)
{
    // Do stuff after every request to your application...
});

Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Request::forged()) return Response::error('500');
});

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::to('login');
});
```

And when I click on the links pointing to these routes, I've get a 
simple Error: 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): from chrome.

How can I fix this?

The site currently located at: [site](http://dev.manticor.org/pumpcity/public)

Comment: I am running into this exact same problem. I works great locally but only the index page shows up on my server. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having a similar problem, and I resolved it deleting the line:

> Route::controller(Controller::detect());

I'm using named Url's. Give it a try.

Comment: This didn't fix it fully, but I realized later that the order I declare my routes does matter really much.

Answer (score 1):

At least on my end I was able to fix this problem by adding. `RewriteBase /` to the .htaccess file. Now everything seems to be working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you register the controller if you haven't.

```
Route::controller(array('site'));
```

If you're using Apache on your server, make sure `mod_rewrite` is on and configured as well as a decent `.htaccess` rule set, laravel comes with a pretty decent `.htaccess` for Apache servers.

Also make sure you have removed the 'index.php' base url from Application config.

These are probably the most common reasons why Routes don't work. You can also test your routes from the command line that makes this process a little simpler:

```
php artisan route:call get about
```

Comment: I've got the .htaccess which Laravel gives you by default. Also I removed the index.php part from the urls. Also mod_rewrite is enabled, that's why I can't figure it out why my routes aren't working.

Comment: Have you tried loading the controllers in manually `Route::controller(array('site', 'ajax'));` ?

Comment: Yes, though it's not working. The thing is the whole site works beautifully on my local dev environment (I use XAMPP for this) but not on the server :(.

Comment: What web server is your remote using? I also seem to remember Chrome doing this on a couple of my sites a while ago where clearing the cache actually solved this...

Comment: System Linux server 3.8.1 #1 SMP Sun Mar 3 09:59:20 CET 2013 x86_64
Apache Version Apache/2.2.24

From phpinfo().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29616/discussion-between-david-barker-and-peaks)

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the root route, in your case :

```
Route::get('/','site@index');
```

at the bottom of the routes.php file

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using Linux, but in case this is applicable for future readers with the same issue:

For me, the issue was that I am running my app on Windows Server 2008 R2 and I hadn't set up the htaccess properly through my IIS Manager.  I hadn't realized I needed to do this because for other sites, my htaccess files were working fine, but none of them were using mod_rewrite.

The solution was to install "IIS URL Rewrite Module 2", which I then could use from the IIS Manager, where I would choose to "Import" everything from the default htaccess file included with Laravel.

After that, all pages loaded, not just the index.